Google Meet: Update Space and add Members API returning 403 error
We are in the developer preview program and have access to v2beta. Everything worked 2 weeks ago when we implemented our Co-Host feature.
1 week ago we got 403 Permission denied errors on the writeable requests:
PATCH /v2beta/spaces/:id
POST /v2beta/spaces/:space_id/members

The readable requests still work:
GET /v2beta/spaces/:id
GET /V2beta/spaces/:space_id/members

The authorized user has the following Auth scopes enabled and accepted when connecting their account:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.created

We checked the oauth scopes, reconnected the Google account. But nothing helps.
Response of the described failing requests are:
403 Forbidden
Permission denied on resource MeetingSpace (or it might not exist)

The MeetingSpace does exist, because the GET request do work!
We even tried to create an issue at Google's issue tracker, but ironically we always get an Access denied there as well (And we tried with different google user accounts and browsers.) See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/372493820.
Maybe that issue is connected. Any help would be appreciated, because we do not want to write a chatbot to add Members to a Google Meet Space, if it is possibly via API.

I posted an answer to the question you linked. I don't have access to the beta and haven't tested any PATCH requests myself, but I suspect it's the same issue as the other question. The TL;DR version is that the meetings.space.created scope now only allows you to act on Meeting spaces that your app has created, so you can try that as a workaround.

@Daniel We created the google meeting by the app, but via Google Event insert developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert by setting conferenceData.createRequest as described in the documentation. Do you think that's an issue? i can try creating the calendar event and afterwards the meeting space manually and see if that works...

I actually ran into the exact same thing. It only worked for us when I created it with the spaces.create method. You can then still add it manually on the event. My guess again is that here it's Google Calendar creating the Meet link for you so it still doesn't count as your app.

We created the Google meeting by the app (see Daniel's comment), but via Google Event insert  by setting conferenceData.createRequest.
This was not working, so we changed the code from making 1 POST request to making 2 POST requests to the Google API and setting the conferenceData with the returned meeting (space) resource from the create-space request:
POST https://meet.googleapis.com/v2beta/spaces

POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?conferenceDataVersion=1

{
  summary: "Event title",
  ...,
  conferenceData: {
    conferenceId: meeting.meetingCode,
    entryPoints: [{ entryPointType: 'video', uri: meeting.meetingUri }],
    conferenceSolution: { key: { type: 'hangoutsMeet' } }
  }
}

Now the POST /v2beta/spaces/:space_id/members is working and not returning a 403 Forbidden anymore. I still think this is a bug from Google API!
